# Downloading unofficial applications with developer ID signature

Tags: macos, applications, virus

Recently I have download a suite application from a torrent. The application installation was the "official" application installer plus a configuration file that was replaced the official configuration file in the application to make it work.
When I was installed the application installer, the Mac OS X didn't blocked it as a not identifier developer, so I suppose that this installation process is not something like a virus?

My question If I download an application not from the official website, and the OS X find it as an identifier developer, there is no chance that this application is affected by virus?

Comment: Why would you want to download an app from an external source instead of the AppStore?

Comment: It is very expensive app (1000£+)

Comment: As @Rob said in his answer, we do not want to lecture you but also do not want to be a part of illegal activity. Those people spend lots of they time creating the product, they had to pay they bills and feed they kids. It is not fair to steal from them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Illegal software downloads.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've placed a flag before putting the answer up myself too. I do not know if allowed but the facts don't hurt as stated in my answer I think? -- Indeed the program does not cost 1000 pounds for nothing, might be Adobe I know their prices are high too. -- I don't know any app costing that much in the AppStore tbh.

Comment: The question is not about how to download illegal apps, but If the applications which are download illegally, if OS X "accepted" as trusted developer even IF this was download illegally, is there any chance of virus? or modify application?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt if we support installing such (cracked) software, but I can at least give you the facts as I'm not explaining how to download or modify it to crack it.

If you're talking about an **.app** which is originally downloaded from the Mac AppStore in this case, I can explain you the following details:

- Apps like this have their own [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) (this is the same on iOS) and they cannot perform any action outside it. (Without a jailbreak for example on iOS or installer on OS X) - *this counts for all apps in the App Stores since 2012.*
- If the **.plist** file or some relevant information in the **View Package Contents** is edited, so the sandbox thinks you're the original owner - you can run it.

The application cannot get out of the sandbox as explained, thus cannot ruin your Mac - unless you have to give it administrator privileges by a prompt.

Comment: thank you, but I think you didn't answer my question, or I didn't understand well, if OS X "accepted" as trusted developer even IF this was download illegally, is there any chance of virus? or modify application?